# Is there "optimized" screen aspect ratio in Dota 2?

Tags: dota-2

In StarCraft 2 the aspect ratio of 16:9 gives a noticeable advantage over 16:10 because the visibility is always 'fixed' between the top and bottom frame of the screen. Therefore the wider the screen is, the more visibility the player has (and more units fit on the screen).

Does similar limitation exists in Dota 2?
 1. How exactly does aspect ratio affect the visibility?
 2. Also, does the screen resolution affect the visibility or max camera distance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are 2 Screenshots, one made in 16:10 and one made in 16:9.

16:9 has a slight advantage in visibility. I was unable to see a difference in max possible zoom distance.

[1600x900](http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=2012-04-27_00002cxjm8.jpg)

[1680x1050](http://www.abload.de/image.php?img=2012-04-27_00003blk88.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! By looking at the screens I can tell it works just exactly the same as StarCraft II - the space between the  top and bottom is always the same, so a wide screen is the way to go!